# Core Text (OS X and iOS) and TeX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-text, tex

I am trying to write some OS X and iOS utilities that can leverage TeX typesetting for math equations (similar to Apple's Grapher.app). What is the best way to go about this in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch? Does Core Text have the power I need to do TeX typesetting, or do I need to go lower-level than Core Text? Any advice and recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know, what you mean with "deeper". If this means to get to a lower-level API: No. With Core Text you can layout letters in different sizes at any position. At least nothing else is needed.

If you mean that you have to do additional work providing the layout, the answer is "Yes." Things like fractions,  labels and so on has to be done manually. I'm pretty sure that the type setters of core text are not able to do that.